# iOS set UILabel value

Tags: objective-c

I would like to append the word "Completed" to the end of the self.myLabel.text, following the value returned from numberValue.

So, say numberValue returns 234, I would like self.myLabel.text to become "234 completed".

I am sure this is a simple task, but am missing the obvious?!

The code used to display the number only is:-

```
self.myLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", numberValue];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
self.myLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d completed", numberValue];
```

Comment: Thank you. That is great! Out of interest, if I wanted to precede the numberValue with the word "completed" what would that syntax be?

Comment: You'd just change the format string to "completed %d". The NSString's method stringWithFormat just looks for formatting characters and replaces them with values in order of appearance. E.g. if you have %d anywhere in your string, and provide a variable, it will put that variable's value in place of %d.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `NSNumber` (or any similar object class such as `NSString`, `NSDecimalNumber`, `NSDate`), use the `%@` format string.

So for your example: `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ completed", numberValue];`

If you are using `NSInteger`, you can use the `%d`/`%ld` (long integer) formats.

Answer (score 0):

if numberValue is integer use the following:

```
self.myLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d completed", numberValue];
```

if numberValue is of type NSNumber or some unknown type just use as follow:

```
self.myLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ completed", numberValue];
```

Answer (score 0):

As their is a first result in google and has not been updated for swift:

Swift:

```
var the_label
the_label.text = "the text to assign"
```